# How to build or include Korge sample projects?

Tags: korge

Quick reference:

https://github.com/korlibs/korge-next

How do I run or include the samples directory for compilation?

Answer (score 0):

In the `settings.gradle` file, you can include individual samples project like this:

`include(":samples:fleks-ecs")`

You can also just include the entire samples directory, but this is not recommended as it takes awhile to build.